# How to download multiple videos at a time?

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, swift4.1

I want to download multiple videos at a time but in my case upto 3 videos downloaded properly but after that its override previous one.
I am using urlSession downloadTask for running in background and save into document directory.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: try this tutorial and hope this  tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift can help to solve your question .